# New to C, want to pass the struct to function, then return the value to main. Any help is appreciated

Tags: c, function, struct

This code is supposed take the members of the struct, and get values for each one in the function. Then, pass the value to the main() and display the information to the user. I am trying to build a bigger program and this is a really important part. I keep getting several errors, mainly with the function. The errors are as follows:

```
main.c:18:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 final_expenses(struct expense)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘final_expenses’:

main.c:21:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^

main.c:30:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 struct expenses expense_total(){
                                ^

main.c:18:1: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
 final_expenses(struct expense)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.c:18:23: error: parameter name omitted
 final_expenses(struct expense)
                       ^~~~~~~

main.c:63:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Struct for the function */
typedef struct expense{
    float housing;
    float home_ins;
    float gas;
    float car_pay;
    float car_ins;
    float food;
    float utilities;
    float wifi;
    float loan_pay;
    float phone_bill;
    float savings;
    float entertainment;
} expenses;

final_expenses(struct expense)

int main()
{
    final_expenses;

    s = final_expenses();
    printf("\t\t\tBudget Tracker: ");
    printf("Final expenses total out to be: %*f", final_expenses);
    return 0;
}
/*Function for calculating the total expense */
struct expenses expense_total(){

    struct expenses;
    float final_expenses;

    printf("How much do you pay for your housing? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.housing);
    printf("How much do you pay for your home insurance? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.home_ins);
    printf("How much do you pay for gas? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.gas);
    printf("How much do you pay for your car payment? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.car_pay);
    printf("How much do you pay for your car insurance? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.car_ins);
    printf("How much do you pay for your food? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.food);
    printf("How much do you pay for your utilities? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.utilities);
    printf("How much do you pay for your wifi? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.wifi);
    printf("How much do you pay for your loan payment? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.loan_pay);
    printf("How much do you pay for your phone bill? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.phone_bill);
    printf("How much do you pay for your savings? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.savings);
    printf("How much do you pay for your entertainment? ");
    scanf("%f", &expenses.entertainment);
    /* Code for the actual calculation of the total expense */
    final_expense = expenses.housing + expenses.home_ins + expenses.gas + expenses.car_pay + expenses.car_ins + expenses.food + expenses.utilities + expenses.wifi + expenses.loan_pay + expenses.phone_bill + expenses.savings + expenses.entertainment;

    return final_expenses;
}
```

Comment: `final_expenses(struct expense)` needs a `;`.  `s` needs to be defined.

Comment: The line after the `struct` that says `final_expenses(struct expense)` needs a return type (either `struct expense` or `expenses`) and a semicolon.  The line `final_expenses;` inside `main()` is mostly meaningless — it might evaluate a function pointer if the declaration of `final_expenses()` is fixed. You didn't define `s`. The function returns `struct expenses` but you defined `struct expense`.  The list goes on...